# Reformatting data with duplicates in some columns but unique values in others

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to reformat a spreadsheet of records and am struggling.

What I have:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Essentially, there are a multitude of places/sites, and many have had measurements for different parameters done at different dates. I want there to be one single row for each unique date corresponding to the sites, with all the parameters being columns and their values in their corresponding rows. I have tried multiple variations of grouping by date and place ID and transposing but that doesn't get me to where I want. As you can probably tell, I'm fairly new to this.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of data.  Copy/paste the data itself into your question.

Comment: Probably something like `df.stack`...

Comment: `df.pivot(index = ['Place_ID', 'Date'], columns='Parameter_Name', values = 'Parameter_Value')`

Comment: @Chris and @Z Li, thank you so much! pivot_table and pivot were the way to go! I appreciate the swift and helpful response. Have a great day! :)